# Changing tab bar item background color without affecting the tint

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

I am new to iOS and I was stuck in design.  I have searched through several posts but none of them helps.

Most of the posts have suggested to replace the whole tab bar item with image which I don't think is a good idea.

I would expect something like configuration in the storyboard (e.g: User Defined Run Time Attributes) that can help to change the background color of an item without affecting its TINT COLOR.

This is the result I am trying to achieve.

[image]

Comment: PLZ don't scream in your title

Comment: noted, sorry about that :(

Answer (score 1):

You can set background image tabbar like this way, it would be better to customize the tabbar controller by this way.

In Header file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CustomTabBarController : UITabBarController

-(void) setBGView;

@end
```

In M file.

```
#import "CustomTabBarController.h"

@implementation CustomTabBarController
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self setBGView];
}
-(void)setBGView
{
    // Background
    UIImageView* bgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"TabBG.png"]] ; //You can create single color image  or Single Color view to add 
    bgView.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height-60, elf.view.frame.size.widdth, 60);
    [self.view addSubview:bgView];

@end
```

HTH, Enjoy Coding!!

Comment: Hi Viral, I've follow the way you suggested and ended up with the image like this : http://postimg.org/image/gbevrvjtx/ , ignore my bad cutting skill, the whole tab bar are filled with red rectangle now, I have tried the insertSubview method and still can't get the expected output

Comment: " I have tried the insertSubview method and still can't get the expected output " means?

Comment: At first, i suspected that the rectangle was overlapping the image and title of the tab bar item, so i use [self.view insertSubview:bgView atIndex:0]; to test it out , however the red rectangle is not visible. I have posted the expected output in my question , where the red rectangle only occupying the selected tab bar item and does not overlapping other  component in it

Comment: Just try out this in class `viewDidLoad()` method of UItabbar subview class with
`UITabBar *tabBar = self.tabBar ;`

`[tabBar setSelectionIndicatorImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"TabBGImage.png"]];`

Comment: Hi @VirajSavaj, thanks again for your help, "setSelectionIndicatorImage" is the one i am looking for, and your example is straightforward and useful

Comment: i do not have enough reputation to do so :( sorry , thank you from the deepest of my heart

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @ViralSavaj and tagyro from
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26484047/setselectionindicatorimage-is-of-wrong-size-for-iphone-6-and-iphone-6)

I manage to achieve the output similar to my question, seem like "setSelectionIndicatorImage" is the only way to achieve the output like this.

However, the output might not be good when you run in other devices, one way to resolve this problem is to draw a shape according to the device resolution, you can get the snippets from the above link

beware of the code you reused from @tagyro

```
CGSize tabSize = CGSizeMake(CGRectGetWidth(self.view.frame)/5, 49);
```

you might want to change the /5 according to your number of tabs, in my case, i only need to put 4 to get the job done